# проблема с перегрузкой с++

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

static size_t StrLen(const char* _str);
static void StrCpy(char* in_str, const char* src_str);
static char* StrCat(char*& str1, const char* str2);

class String
{
public:
    // Класс-обёртка над строкой, введённая для возможности определения своего operator+
    //
    // вся эта затея исключительно для того, чтобы перейти от неподконтрольного
    // и вообще бессмысленного operator +(char*, char*) к нашему operator+ (Literal&, char*).
    class Literal
    {
    public:
        explicit Literal(char** handledString);

        void operator +(char *s);
        void operator ==(char *s);

        operator char*() const;

        Literal& operator=(const char* in);

    private:
        char** str_;
    };

    String();
    String(size_t);
    String(const String&);
    ~String();

    void showArray();
    String StrOrder();

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, String&);
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, String&);

    Literal operator[](size_t j);
    friend String operator*(String&, String&);

private:
    size_t sizeOfArray;
    char **str;

};

String::String(size_t size)
    : sizeOfArray(size)
    , str(new char *[sizeOfArray])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++)
    {
        str[i] = new char[2048];
    }
}

String::String()
{
    sizeOfArray = 3;
    str = new char *[sizeOfArray];
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++)
    {
        str[i] = new char[2048];
    }
}

String::String(const String& obj)
    : sizeOfArray(obj.sizeOfArray)
    , str(new char *[sizeOfArray])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++)
    {
        str[i] = new char[2048];
        ::StrCpy(str[i], obj.str[i]);
    }
}

String::~String()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++)
    {
        delete[] str[i];
    }
    delete[] str;
}

void String::showArray()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++)
    {
        std::cout << str[i] << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

String String::StrOrder()
{
    for (int j = 0; j < sizeOfArray - 1; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray - 1; i++)
        {
            char** tmp = new char *[sizeOfArray];

            for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++)
            {
                tmp[i] = new char[2048];
            }

            if (strcmp(str[i], str[i + 1]) > 0)
            {
                tmp[i] = str[i];
                str[i] = str[i + 1];
                str[i + 1] = tmp[i];
            }
        }

    }
    return *this;
}

String::Literal String::operator[](size_t j)
{
    if (j < sizeOfArray)
    {
        return Literal(&str[j]);
    }
}


String::Literal::Literal(char** handledString)
    : str_(handledString)
{
}

void String::Literal::operator +(char *s)
{
    StrCat(*str_, s);
}

void String::Literal::operator ==(char *s)
{
    StrCpy(*str_, s);
}

String::Literal::operator char*() const
{
    return *str_;
}

String::Literal& String::Literal::operator=(const char* in)
{
    ::StrCpy(*str_, in);

    return *this;
}



static size_t StrLen(const char* _str)
{
    size_t size = 0;
    for (; _str[size] != '\0'; size++);
    return size;
}

static void StrCpy(char* in_str, const char* src_str)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < StrLen(in_str); i++)
        in_str[i] = src_str[i];
}

static char* StrCat(char*& str1, const char* str2)
{
    const size_t sz = StrLen(str1) + StrLen(str2);

    char* const ts = new char[sz + 1];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < StrLen(str1); i++)
        ts[i] = str1[i];
    for (size_t ii = StrLen(str1), j = 0; ii <= sz; ii++, j++)
        ts[ii] = str2[j];

    delete str1;
    str1 = ts;

    return str1;
}

String operator*(String &a, String &b)
{
    if (a.sizeOfArray > b.sizeOfArray)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < b.sizeOfArray; i++)
        {
            if (strcmp(a[i], b[i]))
            {
            }
            else
                b[i] = "";
        }
    }
    else
        for (int i = 0; i < a.sizeOfArray; i++)
        {
            if (strcmp(a[i], b[i]))
            {
            }
            else
                b[i] = "";
        }
    String _a(a.sizeOfArray + b.sizeOfArray);
    for (int i = 0; i < a.sizeOfArray; i++)
    {
        _a[i] == a[i];
    }
    for (int ii = a.sizeOfArray, j = 0; j < b.sizeOfArray; j++,ii++)
    {
        _a[ii] == b[j];
    }
    return _a;
}

void mergeObjects(String *a, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        std::cin >> a[i];
    }
    String _a(3);
    _a[0] = "";
    _a[1] = "";
    _a[2] = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        _a[0] + a[i][0];
        _a[1] + a[i][1];
        _a[2] + a[i][2];
    }
    _a.StrOrder();
    std::cout << _a;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, String& obj)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < obj.sizeOfArray; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Введите строку номер " << i << ": ";
        is.getline(obj[i], 2048);
    }
    return is;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,  String& obj)
{
    int a;
    a=obj.sizeOfArray;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        std::cout << obj[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return os;
}


int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    int a_;
    std::cin >> a_;
    String a1(5);
    std::cin >> a1;
    int n = 3;
    String *a = new String[n];
    mergeObjects(a, n);
    system("pause");
}
```

проблема в том, что если нет `std::cin>>a_;` вообще любого cin, то все работает супер, а если есть, то в выводе класса пропускает одну строчку.

Comment: Флашить вывод не забываете? И при чем тут перегрузка?

Comment: я новичок в плюсах, и не знаю, что такое флашить, я думал это дело в перегрузке

Comment: флашить - значить вызвать `flush`, прямо или косвенно (посредством `endl` например). Невызывание `flush` - самая частая причина обрывающегося вывода в `cout`.

Comment: в функции StrOrder дважды используется i. Посмотрите внимательно. Плюс, похоже, большая несостыковка new[]/delete[]

Comment: после `cin >> a_;` добавьте `cin.ignore(10000, '\n');` Ну и не забудьте пофиксить неинициализированные массивы.

Comment: спасибо, помогло